# I am getting the error: Too many open files after writing a lot of files in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I have a script which generates like 16000 html pages and saves it in the system. after 1013 pages i get the error: Too many open files.

This is the Ruby code which generates the files

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p "public/users_directory/#{DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE}/#{prefix}"
FileUtils.mkdir_p "public/users_directory/#{DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE}/#{prefix}/#{n/1000}"

html_file = File.new("public/users_directory/#{DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE}/#{prefix}/#{n/1000}/#{n}.html", "w")
html_file.write(html)
html_file.close
```

as you can see i close the file in the last line....

Does somebody know what i am doing wrong here? I have Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS

Thanks a lot

Edit:

This is the whole script

```
    def self.fetching_directory_page(n=1, letter = nil)
      id = letter == '' ? "" : "/#{letter.upcase}"
      url = "this is a valid url :)"
      agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
      page = agent.get(url)
      html = page.search('div#my_profile_body').to_html

      prefix = id == '' ? 'all' : letter
      FileUtils.mkdir_p "public/users_directory/#{DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE}/#{prefix}"
      FileUtils.mkdir_p "public/users_directory/#{DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE}/#{prefix}/#{n/1000}"

      html_file = File.new("public/users_directory/#{DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE}/#{prefix}/#{n/1000}/#{n}.html", "w")
      html_file.write(html)
      html_file.close

      puts "+ CREATED #{prefix}/#{n/1000}/#{n}.html" 

      new_url = page.parser.xpath("//a[@class='next_page']")[0]['href'] rescue nil

      if new_url.present?
        self.fetching_directory_page(n+1, letter)
      end
    end
```

It is fetching all the users of my users directory and saves the page for caching reasons. It generates 16000 files in total.

This is results for ulimit-a

```
    core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
    data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
    scheduling priority             (-e) 0
    file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
    pending signals                 (-i) 24640
    max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
    max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
    open files                      (-n) 24000
    pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
    POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
    real-time priority              (-r) 0
    stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
    cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
    max user processes              (-u) 24640
    virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
    file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

After editing /etc/security/limits i dont get the error `Too many open files` but it just gets stuck

`lsof -u username` returns a list of more or less 600 entries and it **doesnt** change while doing the script

Comment: There must be something else in your script. I've tested ruby 1.8.7/1.9.2 on OSX and a 2.6.30 kernel - on Linux, even the GC closes files faster than I can open them (when running lsof in between)

Comment: can you paste the output of this commmand "ulimit" , run it in the terminal

Comment: Are you sure that it's all of the important code?  I tried creating a lot of files with code you provided and it worked without problems.

Comment: Use lsof while this programming is running to find which file handles are open. Just put a sleep after creating one file, so that you get time to run lsof. "lsof -c ruby" or "lsof -p <PID>" ..

Comment: @Rishav 'ulimit' gets me `unlimited` from the terminal

Comment: I edited the post. i dont have the program lsof installed i think. I get a comment not found

Comment: it probably want solve your issue but you should get better results with instantiating agent only once `@agent ||= lambda do agent=WWW::Mechanize.new; agent.max_history=0; agent; end.call`

Comment: @mpapis, Thanks! it doesnt sove the error but your code is better :)

Comment: Somebody knows a command to manually close files? I would like to rescue this error and closing all the files in the directory manually and run it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open files weren't causing the problem. It was the recursive method. I changed that and things work great.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not certain if this is the best approach to your problem, but it may help:

Try commenting out half the code. If it still has the problem, then comment out half of the remainder. Keep on doing this until the problem goes away. Once the problem's gone away, try uncommenting some of the code. Keep on doing that until the problem returns. More likely than not, the line you've just uncommented is related to the bug. This approach to a problem is sometimes called a "binary chop".

With this particular case, you may want to make sure that whatever's calling `fetching_directory_page` isn't opening a new file each time without closing it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in operating system, not in ruby script itself.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502545/too-many-open-files-error-on-ubuntu-8-04/1333450#1333450) advice from an earlier SO question:

> Check how many files your current user has permission to open: in terminal run `ulimit -a` and check the line **open files (-n)**. Default is 1024.
>
> To fix this you have to modify the following file: `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this but this wont raise the error but it will just get stuck at the same point... :(

Answer (score 1):

It's a minor point, but Ruby supports using a block with `File.open`, which will automatically close the opened file. It's considered idiomatic to use that form with Ruby, instead of the way you're doing it:

```
html_file = File.new("public/users_directory/#{DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE}/#{prefix}/#{n/1000}/#{n}.html", "w")
html_file.write(html)
html_file.close
```

should be:

```
File.open("public/users_directory/#{DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE}/#{prefix}/#{n/1000}/#{n}.html", "w") do |html_file|
  html_file.print html
end
```

From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-open) for `IO.open`, from which File.open is inherited:

> With no associated block, IO.open is a synonym for ::new. If the optional code block is given, it will be passed io as an argument, and the IO object will automatically be closed when the block terminates. In this instance, ::open returns the value of the block.