# error while running a stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hey i am Getting this error

```
Out of resources when opening file '#sql_d1c_152.MYD' (Errcode: 24)
```

in mysql when running a stored procedure

Comment: possible duplicate of [Too many open files error on Ubuntu 8.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502545/too-many-open-files-error-on-ubuntu-8-04)

Comment: i have a windows server, not linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit on the number of files you can open simultaneously (1024 I think). 
You may want to increase the open_files_limit in your MySQL configuration file.

More here: 
[MySQL: Errcode: 24](http://major.io/2007/08/19/mysql-errcode-24-when-using-lock-tables/)
and here [MySQL Bugs: Errcode 24](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35889)

Some more Information about ideal open_files_limit size: [mysql: How do you determine the ideal 'open_files_limit' setting value?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18036/mysql-how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-open-files-limit-setting-value)